# element.click binds mouse right click when I use mobileEmulation option

Tags: angularjs, selenium, protractor, selenium-chromedriver

I have an issue running tests with the mobileEmulation option, so when I try to bind a click event on every element it acts like long tap/touch/click instead of left click, but it works perfectly on desktop tests, does anyone know what could be the problem ?

```
<div class="m-t">
    <button type="submit" class="btn primary btn-block" ng-disabled="working" ng-mouseover="validateInputs()">
        <span ng-show="!working">Sign up for free</span>
        <span ng-show="working">Please wait...</span>
    </button>
</div>
```

Here is my selector example:

> browser.element(by.css('[type="submit"]')).click();

Please check out my webdriver manager version and configurations below:

This is my config:

```
seleniumAddress: 'http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub',
capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome',
        'chromeOptions': {
        // Get rid of --ignore-certificate yellow warning
        args: ['--no-sandbox', '--test-type=browser'],
        // Set download path and avoid prompting for download even though
        // this is already the default on Chrome but for completeness
        prefs: {
            'download': {
                'prompt_for_download': false,
                'directory_upgrade': true,
                'default_directory': path.join(__dirname, 'dummy-files', 'tmp')
            }
        },
        'mobileEmulation': {
            'deviceName': 'iPhone 6'
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my webdriver manager version:

```
$ sudo webdriver-manager status
webdriver-manager: using global installed version 12.0.6
I/status - selenium standalone version available: 3.8.1 [last]
I/status - chromedriver version available: 2.34 [last]
I/status - geckodriver version available: v0.19.1 [last]
I/status - android-sdk is not present
I/status - appium is not present
```

Comment: Can you please provide an html of the sample object.

Comment: Hey @PaulCo, thanks for reply I have updated post and provided html snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a bug in chromedriver 2.34 https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=2172. For now downgrading chromedriver to 2.33 should fix the issue. It looks like you are probably running `webdriver-manager update` to start your test. you can just add `--versions.chrome=2.33` to run a different version

Alternatively you can change your click to a tap:

`browser.touchActions().tap(el).perform();`